# Rails Active Record - Save multiple objects at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I took a look a this question and didn't found any answer that worked for me.

I have, for example a Project model, which has_many tasks. I would like to create, from an array of attributes, many tasks for some project. So, in my project model, I would have a method like this (simplified example):

```
def create_tasks(tasks)
   tasks.map{|t| Task.create(project: self, name: t.name)}
end
```

The problem is, for each task, it will make a hit on my db, and for a large number of records that wouldn't be desirable. How could I do that so ActiveRecord will make only one call to my database?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each call for insertion into database will be done separately (in different transactions). But you could decrease a total delay wrapping all creations in a single transaction.

```
Task.transaction do
    tasks.each{ |task| Task.create(...) }
end
```

In this case all your creations will be wrapped in one atomic db transaction.

Take a look at [`transaction`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) documentation.

Also you could try [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna do that. Also, do you think that would be good to use threads for doing each insert?

Comment: also, there's a typo on "create"

Comment: If you're talking about [`Thread`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Thread.html), they are for concurrent (not parallel) programming. You won't get any profits of using it.